# Difference between different numerical propagators

Tags: propagation

As a school project, I'm trying to model the evolution of a space-debris population orbiting around Earth. By doing researches, I found several numerical propagators.

Though, I couldn't find any article clearly explaining the difference between some of them, especially between the SGP4 and the J2 one.

Here is my question:

Which -if any- parameters are taken into account in the SGP4 and not in the J2 that makes it more accurate?

Is it possible to find somewhere NASA Break Up Model's equations?

And is it possible for someone who only knows Python to implement an orbit propagator (such as 2 Bodies or J2) and Break Up model?

Comment: SGP4 models drag and some gravitational coefficients that are of higher order than J2. A J2 model only models J2. As an aside, neither SGP4 nor J2 is particularly accurate.

Comment: I think I got it, thanks for the clarification! However, could you quantify how 'inaccurate' these models are? Which model would you recommend then?